# linear transformation on lebesgue measure theory

Tags: linear-transformations

How to show linear image of lebesgue measurable set is lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

E.g. $m(T(A))=|det T| m(A)$?
Continuous image of measurable set may not be measurable

Comment: That is a basic theorem in every book about Lebesgue integration. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Please use $\rm\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is of rank less than $n$, the image of $f$ has measure zero and the property holds. Otherwise, let $A$ be a measurable set and recall that there is a Borel set $B \subseteq A$ such that $m(A \setminus B) = 0$. Since $f$ has full rank, $f^{-1}$ exists and is linear. Note that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, every linear function is continuous. Now write $f(A) = (f^{-1})^{-1}(B) \cup f(A \setminus B)$. The first set in the union is the continuous preimage of a Borel set, so it's Borel. The second set has measure zero. One way to see this is to notice that $f$ is Lipschitz, so there is some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ (the Lipschitz constant of $f$) for any set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$, we have $km(S) \geq m(f(S))$. But $m(A \setminus B) = 0$, so we're done.